# How to use external libraries in java without an IDE

Tags: java, github, libraries

I'm trying to use this library in my code https://github.com/bhlangonijr/chesslib

The entirety of my code right now is one line, trying to create a new board by using the method they have given

```
Board board = new Board();
```

I read that in order to compile a Java file having a dependency on a jar you have to use

```
$ javac -cp /path/to/jar/file MyProgram.java
```

However, when I originally downloaded the zip file, there weren't any jar files. So I did the command they said to do on the GitHub website

```
mvn clean compile package install
```

and that worked properly and the build was a success. However it created three separate .jar files and none of them work when I try to compile my java file.

This is my first time using external libraries and I have no idea if I'm even close to doing this correctly please help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to compile yourself, just download it manually from jitpack, or better, switch to using Gradle or Maven instead of doing this yourself.